# Swift 4.2 Sort array using a selected property and sort order

Tags: swift, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of custom struct in swift 4.2. I want to sort it out in such a way that

1. Objects with true `isSelected` bool property are always at top and all other objects should be sort by ascending using a property called `sortOrder` (Int).
2. Objects with `isSelected` property should also be sorted by `sortOrder` (ascending way).
   So far I was able to achieve the 1st goal but having some problem with the 2nd.

Here's my code:

```
    myArray.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in

        if item1.isSelected ?? false && item2.isSelected == false  {
      return true
    } else if item2.isSelected ?? false {
     return false
    }

    return item1. sortOrder < item2. sortOrder
      }
```

Please help with the 2nd objective. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the array in place:

```
myArray.sort { item1, item2 in 
   if item1.isSelected == item2.isSelected {
      return item1.sortOrder < item2.sortOrder 
   }
   return item1.isSelected && !item2.isSelected 
}
```

To get a new sorted array

```
let sortedArray = myArray.sorted { item1, item2 in 
   if item1.isSelected == item2.isSelected {
      return item1.sortOrder < item2.sortOrder 
   }
   return item1.isSelected && !item2.isSelected 
}
```

Comment: Nice answer mate!